# Show binary representation of register value in SASM

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, sasm

Can I set SASM to show binary representation of the value I have in the registers (eax, ebx..) during debugging along with the hexadecimal and decimal ones?

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: I've placed my comments into an answer. I couldn't find a question and answer on SO that already addressed this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change the display output of the registers window to display everything in binary. *SASM* is rather limited.

In the *memory and variable* window of SASM you can print registers. Registers are specified with a `$` sign and the register. To print *EAX* you'd use `$eax` and then select `bin` in the pull down for the type.

Alternatively you can print registers with the *GDB* command line at the bottom using `p /t $eax` where *EAX* is any register. The `p` command prints, the `/t` forces binary display.